# 13.04 unity desktop crashes when nvidia-current is installed

Tags: unity, nvidia

I'm running a Dell Vostro 3750 running Ubuntu 13.04.

I've asked previously but hadn't isolated why my Ubuntu system crashed and had to be rebuilt twice.  Now I know.

Installing nvidia-current causes unity to crash.

I immediately tried to remove the package:

sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current

After a reboot, I'm in the same situation.  How do I at least get back to the slow, unoptimized but working graphics I had before without the nvidia driver?

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown the computer
Boot into Recovery Mode --After BIOS load, hold down Shift key to access the grub menu --Once in grub menu, select the entry ending in "(recovery mode)"
From the next menu selected option to enter Root Session
At the root session, execute command 
`mount -o remount,rw /` 
to remount the filesystem as read-write
next

```
apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Then

```
rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

That should do it and get you back to open source driver.